# How to avoid using global variables in javascript slider

Tags: javascript

Bear with me as I am still learning javascript. I have created a simple slider that moves left and right on click. It uses the transform property and moves it 25% in the desired direction.

What I want to do is get into the habit of not using global variables for simple things like this. Below is what I have and it works fine but would appreciate any advice on cleaning it up a little.

```
var wildlifeSlideLeft = document.querySelector('.wildlife__btn--previous');
var wildlifeSlideRight = document.querySelector('.wildlife__btn--next');
var wildlifeSlider = document.querySelector('.wildlife__images__slider');
var wildlifeCurrentPosition = 0

//Wildlife slide left
wildlifeSlideLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideLeft();
});

//Wildlife slide right
wildlifeSlideRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideRight();
});

function slideLeft() {
    if(!(wildlifeCurrentPosition === 0)) {
        wildlifeCurrentPosition = wildlifeCurrentPosition + 25;
        wildlifeSlider.style.transform = "translateX(" + wildlifeCurrentPosition + "%)";
    }
}

function slideRight() {
    if(!(wildlifeCurrentPosition === -100)) {
        wildlifeCurrentPosition = wildlifeCurrentPosition - 25;
        wildlifeSlider.style.transform = "translateX(" + wildlifeCurrentPosition + "%)";
    }   
}
```

Comment: This definitely not the right forum for such questions, [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit

Comment: @rufus , check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858989/how-to-avoid-using-global-variables-in-javascript-slider/52859266#answer-52859266). It has a working example ( snippet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach (minimal code change) would be to wrap your code in an anonymous closure.

Ie:

```
(function (){

    //Your code goes here.

})();
```

This keeps those variable within the scope of the closure rather than attaching them to global scope.

Or for even more readability and maybe even testability. You could name the function and invoke it.

```
function attachSliderEvents() {
    //Your code goes here.
}

attachSliderEvents();
```

Comment: thanks very much for this just what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is keep the variables out of `window`, you could use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
(function () {
  let wildlifeSlideLeft = document.querySelector('.wildlife__btn--previous');
  let wildlifeSlideRight = document.querySelector('.wildlife__btn--next');
  let wildlifeSlider = document.querySelector('.wildlife__images__slider');
  let wildlifeCurrentPosition = 0;

  // Wildlife slide left
  wildlifeSlideLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideLeft();
  });

  // Wildlife slide right
  wildlifeSlideRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideRight();
  });

  function slideLeft () {
    if (!(wildlifeCurrentPosition === 0)) {
      wildlifeCurrentPosition = wildlifeCurrentPosition + 25;
      wildlifeSlider.style.transform = 'translateX(' + wildlifeCurrentPosition + '%)';
    }
  }

  function slideRight () {
    if (!(wildlifeCurrentPosition === -100)) {
      wildlifeCurrentPosition = wildlifeCurrentPosition - 25;
      wildlifeSlider.style.transform = 'translateX(' + wildlifeCurrentPosition + '%)';
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: If you would do it like this you would still be able to access the variables outside of the function because of the `var` keyword, it's better to use `let` in this case as the variable would only be available in the scope of that function .

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

You could use a [Self-Executing Anonymous Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Self-Executing_Anonymous_Function) to wrap everything related to your Slider in a variable named `Slider`.

#### Working Example:

```js
var Person = (function(){

  var personName = 'Johnny';
  
  var getName = () => personName;
  
  return {
    getName: getName
  }  
})();

console.log(Person.getName()); //Johnny
```

#### Further explanation

This way, `Person` has its own [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) ( that contains variables, functions etc ) which you can access using a dot on your variable. Eg. `Slider.slideLeft()`

Comment: thanks for the snippet and detailed answer much appreciated

Comment: You are welcome mate, if you consider my answer a solution, then please do accept it

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to wrap this in a self invoking anonymous function.

```
(function() {
  //insert code here
})();
```

Then you can pass arguments such as the document to it.

```
(function(d){
    var wildlifeSlideLeft = d.querySelector('.wildlife__btn--previous');
    //...
 })(document);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this